# jQuery Masonry gutterWidth and CSS margin-right issue

Tags: html, css, masonry

I need 3 columns block layout, and use jQuery masonry plugin, but having issue with changing qutterWidth in page different sizes.

At first I've tried to set margin-right, but in this case masonry left positioning is not working as should be.

But when I give margin with gutterWidth, I have problems with responsiveness. I'm not expert in jQuery so please help to change gutterWidth when resizing browser, or recomment alternate solution :(

The code is here

```
<div class="masonry">

    <div class="item">
        <p class="item__par">texttexttexttext</p> <a href="" class="">texttexttexttexttexttext</a>

        <div class="item--inner">
            <p>itemitemitemitemitemitemitemitemitem</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p class="item__par">texttexttexttext</p> <a href="" class="">texttexttexttexttexttext</a>

        <div class="item--inner">
            <p>itemitemitemitemitemitemitemitemitem</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
        <p class="item__par">texttexttexttext</p> <a href="" class="">texttexttexttexttexttext</a>

        <div class="item--inner">
            <p>itemitemitemitemitemitemitemitemitem</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
        <p class="item__par">texttexttexttext</p> <a href="" class="">texttexttexttexttexttext</a>

        <div class="item--inner">
            <p>itemitemitemitemitemitemitemitemitem</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
        <p class="item__par">texttexttexttext</p> <a href="" class="">texttexttexttexttexttext</a>

        <div class="item--inner">
            <p>itemitemitemitemitemitemitemitemitem</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item {
    width: 273px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background: lightgray;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    margin-right:50px
}
```

jQ

```
 $('.masonry').masonry({

      itemSelector: '.item',
      gutter: 68
  });
```

Fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/frontDev111/0vhegec1/1/

Update:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        var $gutter = 68;

        if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1200px)").matches) {
            $gutter = 30;
        }
        var $container = $('.masonry');
        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.item',
                gutter: $gutter
            });
        });

    });
```

But I get undefined error because of imagesloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set various gutters based on media queries using [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia). Like this:

```
var $gutter;

if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 480px)").matches) {
    $gutter = 20;
} else if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
    $gutter = 40
} else { 
    // and so on
}

$('.masonry').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    gutter: $gutter
});
```

If you need CSS-like working of this, place the code inside `$(window).resize`:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // code
});
```

This will cause the code to be fired each time the user resizes browser. But please be advised not o put very large and complex scripts inside `resize`, it will drastically decrease performance.

Also consider wrapping your code in a [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) and then fire only these.

Comment: Finally!! thanks a lot!!)) the only issue that after resizing the $gutter is not working untill refresh, but this is not much irritating.Thanks again!!

Comment: Like I said, if you need it to work after resizing, place your code inside `$(window).resize`. This will cause the code to be fired each time the window chances its size.

Comment: oh, did it already, thanks! also I'm having truble when useing it with pagination. When I use "imagesLoaded" function it gaves undefined error. Do you have idea about that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/orh9odvk/ Fiddle seems to be working fine. But I've updated the code using function and making sure that it will fire when the page is loaded AND when user resizes: http://jsfiddle.net/orh9odvk/2/

Comment: using this code I again get "undefined is not a function " error :(

Comment: Then you must have some other code interfering, because it works good on the fiddle, and it's pretty straightforward, so really no place for mistakes ;-) Can you post your entire JS?

Comment: not sure why couldn't get this work in jsFiddle, btw I have included necessary files for pagination. http://jsfiddle.net/frontDev111/orh9odvk/5/
I have also included imagedLoaded plugin and now everything is ok with that, but I get emplty page while jumping to next page.

Comment: You are in fact getting an error, but it's caused neither by imagesLoaded nor Masonry - jPaged is causing it, and I can't help you with this particular plugin since I haven't seet it before ;-)